# Use scaled and moved image from IPhone UIImagePickerController to match marks on overlay image and still match them after choose and merge them both

Tags: iphone, objective-c, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller, scale

UIImagePickerController on edit in preview screen with an overlay image, after scale and move the taken or selected image, to match marks on overlay image, the result edited image don't seems to maintain aspect so when merge both, overlay image and edited image, the edited image don't match the marks on overlay image, like on preview after scale and move.

How can i make the edited image still match the marks of the overlay image, when merged into a single image?

I managed to do this without enable the edit on UIImagePickerController, when i take a picture with the iPhone camera, i can see the overlay image on screen, take the picture so it match the marks on the overlay image, and when i merge them both, the taken picture still match the marks on the overlay image. (I control the orientation and scale for the merge to be successful).

I also manage to get an overlay image on the preview screen(Scale and Move), after selecting a picture from device image library.

I'm using the info dictionary to obtain the UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage, when enable the allowsEditing property of the UIImagePickerController.  Also am aware of the existence of the UIImagePickerControllerCropRect in the info dictionary and the differences between images taken by the device camera and saved images in device library, not necessarily taken with device.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find the answer to this? I am also having the same problem and can not get the correct output of the cropped edited image after preview screen for my overlay image. thanks